# Can't declare new controller - dependency missing

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to declare a second controller to a new view in my page. I have a logincontroller and when I succeed the login I get to the Home.html.

When opening Home.html I get the following error below..It looks like it can't recognize my ModelController/ModalService..What am I missing here?

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/$injector/unpr?p0=ModalServiceProvider%20%3C-%20ModalService%20%3C-%20ModalController

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="PVM">
<head>
<title>My Ang</title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/MyCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>


<script src="Scripts/Services/ModalService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Services/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Controller/LoginController.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Controller/ModalController.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/MyApp.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Home.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ModalController">

<div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="btn btn-group-justified" ng-init="testfunc()">press me</button>
</div>
</div>
```

MyApp.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
    'Authentication',
    'Modal',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
])
.config([
    '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'Login.html'
            })
            .when('/Home', {
                controller: 'ModalController',
                templateUrl: 'Home.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/Login'
            });
    }
]);
```

ModalController.js:

```
angular.module('Modal')
.controller('ModalController',
['$scope', 'ModalService',
function ($scope, ModalService) {

    $scope.testfunc = function() {
        alert('weeee');
    }


}]);
```

ModalService.js:

```
angular.module('Modal', []);

angular.module('Modal')
.factory('ModalService'
['$http',
function ($http) {
    var service = {};



    return service;
}
]);
```

Comment: Can you post declaration script for ModalService?

Comment: @mtndesign updated question

Comment: In ModalService.js, there is a HomeService called without injection. I think you're getting two errors, but you're asking about latter one. First error would be `cannot find HomeService ` and because of that your ModalService cannot declared and that's why you're getting second error of `ModalService cannot be found`.

Comment: Oh, and you're trying to inject ModalService, while declaring it, that could be the first error too.

Comment: Oh I missed that..I have updated the question again..But still same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `app.js` after including services and controllers. And controllers after services.

it should be like this:

```
<script src="Scripts/Services/ModalService.js"></script>  <!--ModalService is being defined here -->
<script src="Scripts/Services/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Controller/LoginController.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Controller/ModalController.js"></script> <!-- ModalService is being injected here -->
<script src="Scripts/MyApp.js"></script> <!-- All of the things are set in place here -->
```

In fact, the best practice is to include all of them in the bottom of your `<body>`.

Comment: This didn't work either..when putting MyApp.js last it complains about Authentication module

Comment: Is your auth service defined against your auth module? If so then your defining your auth module in the `myApp.js`. Which is included last causing the new issue. Split the module definitions apart and include the auth module definition before the auth service. Then the myapp module in the myApp file last. This is why im so glad i use a build system like browserify.

Comment: My AuthenticationService is defined against angular.module("Authentication")

Comment: @ste2425 should I define my modules with my service, or with my controller?

Comment: Generally speaking i follow how @mtndesign has suggested. Module -> Services -> Controller -> directives etc. So long as your module is defined before you try to access it your ok. That includes dependencies. Your `auth` module needs to be defined with all its controllers/services etc before `myApp` tries to include it as a dependency.

Comment: @ste2425 I've made an update to my question after all your tips. And it works just like before..Same error concerning ModalController/ModalService.. But now I'm defining it before my service. My AuthenticationService and LoginController works fine though,,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer..The problem was that I was missing a comma :(

ModalService.js should look like this:

```
angular.module('Modal', []);

angular.module('Modal')
.factory('ModalService', <------ COMMA MISSING :(
['$http',
function ($http) {
var service = {};



return service;
}
]);
```